# Formatting javadoc in Enums

Tags: intellij-idea, formatting

I'm looking for a way to set up code formatting to keep javadoc in enums in separate blocks. Right now wrapping of enum members works as intended, but for some reason javadoc comments start/end on the same line as the members
I'd keep getting this:

```
public enum FormatTest {
    FOO, /**
    * some description
    */BAR, BAZ;
}
```

but I want it to look something like this:

```
public enum FormatTest {
    FOO, 
    /**
     * docs either like this
     */
    BAR,
    /** or like this */
    BAZ;
}
```

It works perfectly well for class members strangely enough...

Comment: When you say "class members", do you mean "static members"? Because that's essentially what `enum` values are.

Comment: yes, javadoc on static members is formatted like the comments on "BAR" in my desired formatting example

Comment: @msn even for comma-separated declarations? They are quite rare... try `public static final Integer /** one */ ONE = 1, /** two */ TWO = 2, /** three */ THREE = 3;`

Comment: ah, ok - nope, those seem to have the same problem as enum members ...

Comment: Why use javadoc? It's 2017 already...

Comment: @vikingsteve: I'm open to alternatives, It's just that I'm unaware of any...

Comment: Please follow https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-180049 for updates.

Comment: @nsn you could just drop javadoc completely and use meaningful identifiers to self-document most of the time. Add single line // comments where necessary.

Answer (score 0):

try changing the Code Style settings.

In IntelliJ, go to: **Settings -> Code Style -> Java -> Wrapping and Braces** tab.

Scroll down untill you see **Enum constants**, and change the value to: **Wrap always**.

[See screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ffBHe.jpg)